# What is your best example of a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: single-responsibility-principle, solid-principles

I'm looking for some good examples of code that violates the Single Responsibility Principle.  Don't show me any examples from Uncle Bob's books or web sites since those are plastered all over the internet, like this one:

```
interface Modem
{
    public void dial(String pno);
    public void hangup();
    public void send(char c);
    public char recv();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The granularity of your OO design is a matter of taste and might be inapropriate for others. Thus, I wouldn't look for examples of breaking the single responsibility principle in some business-logic-class, discussing whether it has too much or too little to do.

In my opinion, the best examples (with worst side-effects) come from breaking the layering of your application. F.ex.:

- Performing business logic in the data access layer (whose only responsibility should be providing persistence access to the application)
- Accessing business services from (through) the domain model (whose only responsibility should be to store most of the application's state)
- Performing complex business logic in the view layer (responsible for data presentation & user input)

Comment: Hear, hear!: _"The granularity of your OO design is a matter of taste and might be inappropriate for others."_ Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code from a PHP project I had to take on:

```
class Session
{
    function startSession()
    {
        // send HTTP session cookies
    }

    function activateUserAccount()
    {
        // query the DB and toggle some flag in a column
    }

    function generateRandomId()
    {}

    function editAccount()
    {
        // issue some SQL UPDATE query to update an user account
    }

    function login()
    {
        // perform authentication logic
    }

    function checkAccessRights()
    {
        // read cookies, perform authorization
    }
}
```

I believe this class does waaay to much.

Answer (score 3):

The clue about SRP is to *define* the responsibilities so that your implementation does just that thing. It's like you're making a rule (by giving a class a name and a responsibility) and then trying to follow it.

So if you're not following it you're *either* not defining the rule properly or you're being inconsistent while implementing it (or both, which might actually be the most common case).

I generally find the classes that do not give a half-decent try at defining a single main responsibility or good name to be the best violations. Then you'll just have to read the whole class to try to determine if there's any well defined responsibilities at all.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in most OO languages that I have used, the top-level `Object` class is a good example. In Ruby, for example, the `Object` class (or more precisely the `Kernel` mixin, which gets mixed into `Object`) has 45 public instance methods. Now, some of those are aliases, but there's still got to be at least 20, and they are from all over the place. I can easily identify at least 5 responsibilities.

Now, I don't mean to pick on Ruby. It is my favorite programming language. That's why I used it as an example: because it's the language I'm most familiar with. And I am reasonably sure that what I wrote about Ruby applies 100% also to at least Java and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

It's a qualitative question to ascertain the 'responsibilities' of a class. 
Just looking at a given class code, can in no measure give us an idea of how well it handles it's repsonsibility. 
It is very necessary, atleast as per my experience, to take into account how the requirement changes to the class will propagate to other modules ( or how will the changes from other classes get propagated to this class).

As @schmeedy gives a nice explanation of 'breaking the layering of the system' , which I think is just one of the ways to analyse 'responsibility domain'.

I have attempted to take the discussion little further. My attempts are to define 'responsibility' in a quantitative way.
Some discussions at my blog: http://design-principle-pattern.blogspot.in/2013/12/single-responsibility-principle.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

@interface Spreadsheet : NSObject

- (void)loadFromURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (void)saveToURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (void)drawTo:(CGRect*)targetArea withContext:(CGContextRef *)context;

@end
```

I would argue that the above example violates the SRP.

On the face of it, it is clear that the class is responsible for one thing: Spreadsheets.  It is distinguished from other entities in the Document Management problem domain such as Word Processing.

However, consider the reasons why the Spreadsheet object could change.

There may be a change to the model underlying the Spreadsheet.  This affects load and save code but would not affect how the Spreadsheet is drawn.  So the load/save responsibilities are separate from the drawing responsibilities.  Our class has two responsibilities.

So if we think about all the reasonably foreseeable reasons to change a class, and see that only particular methods on the class would be affected, we see an opportunity to factor out a responsibility to get a more focussed class.

A revised class would be:

```
@interface SpreadsheetEncoder

- (NSData *)encodedSpreadsheet:(Spreadsheet *)spreadsheet;
- (Spreadsheet *)spreadsheetFromEncodedData:(NSData *)data;

@end

@interface Spreadsheet2 : NSObject

- (NSData *)data;
- (instancetype)initSpreadsheetFromData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)drawTo:(CGRect*)targetArea withContext:(CGContextRef *)context;

@end
```

As product development advances, we can ask ourselves again 'what could change' and then refactor the classes to keep them responsible for only one concern.  SRP is only relative to the problem domain and our understanding of it at a given time.

SRP in my view boils down to asking 'what can change?' and 'what would be affected'.  When 'what can change' maps onto only one thing that is affected, you have classes that implement the SRP principle.